# Where to best put a variable, in the class or in the method (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I followed in the code in the Android tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

```
public File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {
File file;
try {
    String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
    file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Error while creating file
}
return file;
```

}

When I add this method to my class, there was an error on this code:

```
return file;
```

That says "File may not have been initialized"

What I did is I transferred the initialization code

```
File file;
```

To the class variable as a class field instead of a local method variable and the error disappeared. Is this the correct way to resolve the issue? Is there no workaround that would keep the variable local in the method and not global in the class?

Comment: `File file = null;`

Comment: Thank you. This works but I decided to keep the initialization in the class with private access modifier since I found out that I need to access that variable in another method. But the code on top works perfectly.

Comment: personally I'd keep it a local variable. your method is `getTempFile` which to me implies a simple getter, but if your setting a global file reference in there that's a side effect. ick. its a matter of style. if you make it a global make sure you document that in the javadoc.

Comment: Interesting input. I forgot to tell everybody that I am a Java newbie. Only a few years experience in PHP OOP and just started coding JAVA less than a week. I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

How about getting rid of it completely

```
public File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {
  try {
    String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
    return File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // Error while creating file
    // well lets say so then
    System.err.println ("Error while creating file ");
    e.printStackTrace ();
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this modification. Looks slick, I am going to try it.

Comment: cool, please also consider to accept and/or upvote this answer

Comment: I'm a newbie to stack, please tell me how, I will gladly do it.

Comment: Not enough reputation yet. But thanks for all the help.

Comment: Two things: wombat.. Consider moving the return null *into* the catch block. That makes your intention even more clear. Ray: you can always accept :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to **limit** visibility. Fields have a default `null` initialization. So the equivalent in the method is

```
File file = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are fine ; especially the one about avoiding the variable completely, but let's answer your question, too:

You put variables where you need them, preferably on the "smallest" scope possible. Meaning that you prefer local variables over class wide fields.  In other words: you only use fields when two or more methods need to use the same information!

Comment: That is exactly what I have in mind. I was having second thoughts in putting it class wide since I only need it locally. I overlooked the null initialization since my experience in Java was only a few days old, the last OOP language where I coded was PHP.

Comment: @GhostCat Nice answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {
File file = null;
try {
    String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
    file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Error while creating file
}
return file;
}
```

You can get rid of local variable file, or just initialize it with null.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Glad to be here on stack.

Comment: glad to help, and you are welcome to give me a thumbs up for the answer :P @RoySelim